# Getting oldest Date SQL Complexity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem which I cannot resolve no matter what without using code, instead of SQL SCRIPT.

I have 2 tables

```
Person
 ID      Name        Type
  1       A           A1
  2       B           A2
  3       C           A3
  4       D           A4
  5       E           A6


PersonHomes

HOMEID         Location     PurchaseDate   PersonID
   1            CA           20160101         1
   2            CT           20160202         1
   3            DT           20160101         2
   4            BT           20170102         3
   5            CT           20160303         1
   6            CA           20160101         2
```

PersonID is foreign key of Person Table

There are no other rowz in the tables

So, we have to show detail of EACH person WITH home

The rule to write output is

- IF Person has SINGLE entry in PersonHomes then use it
- IF Person has MORE than ONE entry in PersonHomes then we have to look at     purchase date, IF they are different then USE the PersonHomes ROW with OLDEST date in it. AND DELETE OTHER ROWS OF HIM
- IF Person has MORE than ONE entry in PersonHomes then we have to look at purchase date, and IF DATES are SAME then USE the ROW with LOWER ID AND DELETE THE OTHER ROWS of HIM

This is very easy to do in code but using SQL it is complex

What I tried was to

```
WITH PERSON (
SELECT * FROM Person)

SELECT * FROM PERSON
INNER JOIN PersonHomes ON Person.ID = PersonHomes.PersonID 
WHERE PersonHomes.PersonID = CASE WHEN (COUNT (*) FROM PersonHomes...)
```

Then I think I can write SQL function ?

I am stuck, Please help!

SAMPLE OUTPUT for PERSON A

```
ID  NAME Type HOMEID  Location    PurchaseDate

1    A    A1     5      CT          20160303
```

For PERSON B

```
ID  NAME Type HOMEID  Location    PurchaseDate

1    A    A2     3      DT          20160101
```

Aiden

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the syntax is clearly not MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so easy to get desired output with SQL. we should write more than one sql queries.

First I created a temp table which consists of home details:

```
select PersonID, count(*) as HomeCount, count(distinct PurchaseDate) as
PurchaseDateCount, min(PurchaseDate) oldestPurchaseDate, min(HOMEID) as
LowerHomeID into #PersonHomesAbstractTable from PersonHomes group by PersonID
```

Then for the output of your first rule:

```
select p.ID, p.NAME, p.Type, ph.HOMEID, ph.Location, ph.PurchaseDate from Person p 
inner join #PersonHomesAbstractTable a on p.ID = a.PersonID 
inner join PersonHomes ph on p.ID = ph.PersonID  
where a.HomeCount = 1
```

For the output of your second rule:

```
select p.ID, p.NAME, p.Type, ph.HOMEID, ph.Location, ph.PurchaseDate
from Person p inner join #PersonHomesAbstractTable a on p.ID = a.PersonID
inner join PersonHomes ph on p.ID = ph.PersonID and 
ph.PurchaseDate = a.oldestPurchaseDate
where a.HomeCount > 1 and a.PurchaseDateCount <> 1
```

And finally for the output of your third rule:

```
select p.ID, p.NAME, p.Type, ph.HOMEID, ph.Location, ph.PurchaseDate
from Person p inner join #PersonHomesAbstractTable a on p.ID = a.PersonID
inner join PersonHomes ph on p.ID = ph.PersonID and 
ph.HOMEID = a.LowerHomeID
where a.HomeCount > 1 and a.PurchaseDateCount = 1
```

Of course there are some other ways, but now this way is come to my mind.

If you want to delete undesired rows, you can use scripts below:

```
delete from PersonHomes where HOMEID in 
(
   select ph.HOMEID from #PersonHomesAbstractTable a 
   inner join PersonHomes ph on a.PersonID = ph.PersonID and 
   ph.PurchaseDate <> a.oldestPurchaseDate
   where a.HomeCount > 1 and a.PurchaseDateCount <> 1

   union

   select p.HOMEID from #PersonHomesAbstractTable a 
   inner join PersonHomes ph on a.PersonID = ph.PersonID and 
   ph.HOMEID <> a.LowerHomeID
   where a.HomeCount > 1 and a.PurchaseDateCount = 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the correct answer, we only do it by using temporary tables to hold record of what we are doing in each step

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a prioritization query.  I would solve this using `row_number()`:

```
select ph.*
from (select ph.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid
                                order by purchasedate asc, homeid asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from personhomes ph
     ) ph
where seqnum = 1;
```

This doesn't actually change the data in the table.  Although you say `delete`, it seems like you just want a result set with one home per person.

Comment: Can you please review my answer below ? I think we can solve it by this way ?

Comment: Your logic is complex :( Sorry I am not expert. Where is other rows deleted in your SQL ? Can you please briefly explain your logic ? I actually have to DELETE the rows too :(

Answer (score 0):

This is shortest approach got by [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568218/delete-where-both-columns-match#40568345)

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AddressMoveDate DESC) FROM Address
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE RowN > 1
```

Comment: It might be short, but it seems to delete the wrong rows.