# Delete where both columns match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have two tables

```
Person (contain oldest date (farthest in future) when person moved OR WILL moved to another address)

ID                OLDESTADDRESSMOVEDATE

1                     20161117
2                     20171211
3                     20160101


Address           

PersonID             AddressMOVETODATE
 1                       20161117
 1                       20161111
 1                       20141018
 2                       20171211
 2                       20151210
```

Now I want to write a DELETE query which will DELETE FROM ADDRESS THE ROWS for EACH person in PERSON, where AddressMOVETODATE is PREVIOUS THAN the one in OLDESTADDRESSMOVEDATE colum

e.g.

If I run that query the remaining rows in ADDRESS table should be

```
PersonID             AddressMOVETODATE
1                       20161117
2                       20171211
```

I have tried

`DELETE FROM ADDRESS WHERE PERSONID = PERSON.ID and AddressMOVETODATE < Person.OLDESTADDRESSMOVEDATE`

but it is not working. Also, how we will make sure we enter only CORRESPONDING columns of Person table e.g. we do not want to mess up by putting

`Person ID = 1 and Person.OLDESTADDRESSMOVEDATE = 20171211 (of Person 2)`

Please help.

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: May be using Cursor OR INNER JOIN

Comment: Please do not type your question title in ALL CAPS. That's considered SHOUTING here, as it is everywhere else on the web. It will not get you answers any sooner, it makes text harder to read, and it's really rude and annoying. Please be courteous; there are Shift keys on both sides of your keyboard to make them easy to reach, because text that is properly cased is easier to read and understand. Thanks.

Comment: Ooops sorry, won't do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query using row_number, cte and delete

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AddressMoveDate DESC) FROM Address
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE RowN > 1
```

Comment: No need to Add Person.ID inseat of ID above ? How will it know that ID is coming from Person when have not mentioned it in it? We also are not using OLDESTADDRESSMOVEDATE why.

Comment: WOW. good logic but it gives some error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Just remove comma next to PARTITION BY ID it will work

Comment: GREAT! One last question before I mark it as answer, If I also want to UPDATE a column of another table, which has SAME data as Address, but instead of DELETE rows, I want to UPDATE a specific column, where the AddressMOVETODATE is LESS (or previous) than the Maximum value in EACH partition of PERSONID ? How can I update a column with this syntax ?

Comment: not able to understand what you are looking for, you want to update same table or different table? If it is different table then you need to join and update

Comment: Yep different table Sir, I want to SIMULTANEOUSLY delete THOSE PREVIOUS rows from Address table and UPDATE columns in another (PersonPassport) table. The condition in CTE you wrote are EXACTLY same... but requirement says they need rows PersonPassport table updated too. The DATA in Address and PersonPassport IS EXACTLY SAME just two different tables. Can you please help with syntax ?

Comment: You can use the same cte and write different update is option 1, You can output these deleted records and update it in different table is option 2

Comment: If you want both to be in atomic transaction use tran and commit

Comment: AMZAZING, marked it as answer, you are a Genius Sir....one last thing (this is REALLY last :)   There are some records in Address where Dates are SAME for Some partitions. The query you gave REMOVES duplicates and we have only OLDEST date record per partition of Person ID, which is good, but want to ask WHY it DOES NOT delete record with LOWEST PRIMARY key in a partition but with Higher number i.e. deletes 2 not 1 ID ? You have not mentioned in PRIMARY key though